# Handling multiprocessing return values while still creating processes

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing

I have a working selenium script that I am trying to execute on a large amount of data read from an excel sheet, and have the processed output of each script be written to another excel sheet.

I want to run the script to be running on 9 windows at any given time, and the program waits until one of the scripts is done and closes its browser instance before opening a new window with the script in its place.

I had this fully working with threads before but it was slow and upon looking into the matter I understood the difference between threading and processes in python so now I am trying to rewrite my program to use multiprocessing. Here is some pseudo code representing what I was doing with threads before:

```py
data_to_be_written = []    # queue to write stuff in the output sheet

# get the dimensions of the screen and divide it into 3x3 squares to run 9 instances of the script in 9 different windows at a time
free_window_positions = [.....]
def write_result(sheet):
    while processing:
        while not data_to_be_written:
            continue
        data = data_to_be_written.pop(0)
        sheet.append(data)    # excel sheet


def script(data, position)
    # run script on the data
    data_to_be_written.append(output)
    free_window_positions.append(position)    # give back the position so another thread can run


if __name__ == '__main__':
    data = read_excel('sheet.xlsx')
    threading.Thread(target=write_result, args=(output_sheet)).start()
    i = 0
    while i < len(data):
        while not free_window_positions:
            continue
        position = free_window_positions.pop(0)
        threading.Thread(target=script, args=(data[i], position)).start()
        i += 1
```

Now when trying to use multiprocessing the biggest issue was that there was no shared memory, so I couldn't use a common queue which each process writes to, so I tried using return values but the problem is that I need to process the return values in the same loop in which I am creating the processes not later and I am not sure how to do that.